# Can only receive <5b5d> as a response from NSURL query.. Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsurl

I'm trying to receive a correct response from a NSURL POST request in Objective-C.

My script uses PHP to send tyre sizes (4 parameters) which the user has inputted using textfields, (and then presses Submit - IB Action Button1), and then the idea is to output
the response (Quantity in stock) via the self.instock.text label.
However, ResponseData is only showing up on the console as <5b5d>. 
I have already inserted rows in the MySQL database to match the test data from the App, so that's not the problem.
Can anyone see why I only receive this response?
Many, many thanks in advance!!

```
#import "GetQuoteViewController.h"

@interface GetQuoteViewController ()

@end

@implementation GetQuoteViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSLog(@"You entered %@",self.tyrewidth.text);
    [self.tyrewidth resignFirstResponder];
    NSLog(@"You entered %@",self.tyreprofile.text);
    [self.tyreprofile resignFirstResponder];
    NSLog(@"You entered %@",self.wheelsize.text);
    [self.wheelsize resignFirstResponder];
    NSLog(@"You entered %@",self.speedrating.text);
    [self.speedrating resignFirstResponder];
        return YES;
}
- (IBAction)Button1:(id)sender {
    NSString *meme = _tyrewidth.text;
    NSString *meme1 = _tyreprofile.text;
    NSString *meme2 = _wheelsize.text;
    NSString *meme3 = _speedrating.text;



    _displayMeme.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@   %@  %@  %@",meme,meme1,meme2,meme3];
    NSString *rawStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tyrewidth=%@&tyreprofile=%@&wheelsize=%@&speedrating=%@", _tyrewidth.text, _tyreprofile.text, _wheelsize.text, _speedrating.text];
    NSData *data = [rawStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://budget-tyresofhull.com/service2.php"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:data];

    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *err;
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
    NSLog(@"responseData: %@", responseData);
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *name = responseString;
    self.instock.text = name;
}
@end
```

Comment: Have you tested the PHP code using the browser (i.e. writing a test HTML page to call the PHP code)?  Also wouldn't a `POST` request expect the arguments in the request body and not the URL?

Comment: I haven't tested the PHP code yet - thanks for the idea. If I use a INSERT PHP statement, the code works perfectly - it adds to database. But I want it to return a column's value for that row.. I don't follow what you mean about POST arguments?? As the code stands, will this RETURN a value correctly? I'm not an expert on Asynchronous requests.. Many Thanks! ps if I use the browser, such as safari, and use the website address/service2.php, I receive the same result as in the App i.e. [], and not a quantity figure, as expected..